# Ruby Yield to Subclass Method from Superclass Method

Tags: ruby, inheritance, metaprogramming

In Ruby, is it possible to yield to a subclass method from a superclass method without affecting code in the subclass? I'm trying to avoid calling `super` in the subclass.

```
class SuperClass
  def do_something
    puts "getting ready..."
    # how to then yield back to the subclass do_something method?
    puts "done."
  end
end

class SubClass < SuperClass
  def do_something
    # how to first execute the superclass do_something method?
    puts "doing something ..."
  end
end
```

Desired functionality is to specifically call `SubClass.do_something` and receive the following output:

"getting ready..."

"doing something..."

"done."

---

EDIT:

Maybe the real question is: How to DRY-up the code below, removing calls to `self.get_ready` and `self.finish_up` from all subclasses, using any ruby meta-programming technique that keeps those classes DRY:

```
class SuperClass
  def self.get_ready
    puts "getting ready ..."
  end

  def self.finish_up
    puts "done."
  end
end

class SubClassA < SuperClass
  def self.do_something
    self.get_ready
    puts "doing something ..."
    self.finish_up
  end
end

class SubClassB < SuperClass
  def self.do_something
    self.get_ready
    puts "doing something else, a little differently..."
    self.finish_up
  end
end

class SubClassC < SuperClass
  def self.do_something
    self.get_ready
    puts "doing something crazy..."
    self.finish_up
  end
end
```

Comment: Since you have singleton methods, inheritance is irrelevant.

Comment: What you are attempting is a design flaw. `SubClass#do_something` calls `SubClass#do_something`. You can call `SuperClass#do_something` from within it, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In [Practical Object-Oriented Design in Ruby](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321721330), what Sandi Metz recommend you do to overcome calling super is to define a "hook" method in the super-class, which only job would be to get over-written by the child methods. In your case, you could do something like this:

```
class SuperClass
  def self.do_something
    puts "getting ready..."
    do_something_child
    puts "done."
  end

  def self.do_something_child; end
end

class SubClass < SuperClass
  def self.do_something_child
    puts "doing something ..."
  end
end

SubClass.do_something
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're really not open to using `super`, this is pretty much impossible.

With `super`, it's pretty simple:

```
class SuperClass
  def do_something
    puts "getting ready..."
    yield
    puts "done."
  end
end

class SubClass < SuperClass
  def do_something
    super.do_something do
      puts "doing something..."
    end
  end
end
```

On the other hand, without using `super`, this becomes simpler if you are open to multiple methods:

```
class SuperClass
  def do_something
    puts "getting ready..."
    self.actually_do_the_thing
    puts "done."
  end
  def actually_do_the_thing
    raise NotImplementedError
  end
end

class SubClass < SuperClass
  def actually_do_the_thing
    puts "doing something..."
  end
end
```

Comment: yes, the goal is to avoid using any code (including `super`) in the subclass.

Comment: If you want no code in the subclass, how do you expect to have any meaningful difference in behavior in the first place?

Comment: Note that the OP changed the question.